# Wordpress Gravity form - Link to Add to Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using Gravity Forms plugin in Wordpress. In their documentation, it is mentioned that in order to append javascript on form button, I need to use the following code:

```
add_filter( 'gform_submit_button', 'add_onclick', 10, 2 );
function add_onclick( $button, $form ) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( $button );
    $input = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'input' )->item(0);
    $onclick = $input->getAttribute( 'onclick' );
    $onclick .= " addAdditionalAction('Additional Action');";
    $input->setAttribute( 'onclick', $onclick );
    return $dom->saveHtml( $input );
}
```

Now, I want to add Woocommerce Add to Cart code to the said button. From another stackoverflow question I got the following code:

```
global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        $product->is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

I want to append the php script code in place of javascript code above. Please help how can I do the same.

Comment: Did you make headway with this? I'm also struggling to see where to define `addAdditionalAction` and how to add events to it.